# Logon to 3 x Desktops

Tags: windows-7

Our esteemed Head of IT has just delivered to me 3 computers. I am told that they are the forerunner to another 120 that will be arriving in the next couple of weeks.

The intention is that at the new contact centre, each agent will have 3 screens, each powered by a separate computer*. Synergy (www.synergy-foss.org) will be used to allow control of all three computers from a single keyboard/mouse combo from the centre computer.

Whilst this will work I don't really want the user to have to login to the three separate computers. I would like the login to occur on the middle machine, and that login (Active Directory LDAP) to 'pass through' to the left and the right hand machines.

Any ideas?

*I am aware that a single computer with three screens would actually make more sense here, the decision has been made before I get stick my oar in.

Comment: Why 3 machines and not just one machine with three display outputs?

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to login to the other machines via Synergy, even interactively.

Comment: This is an incredibly stupid idea, and I can't think of a way to make it work.  Just set them up as single machines with three displays, and sell the extra 82 computers on eBay.

Comment: @Chopper3 Yes! I am completely aware of how brilliant a design decision this is :/ Part of the problem is that the machines that have been purchased aren't really up to the job of doing everything we need on a single device, hence why there are three of them. Of course a single, decent, powerful machine would have worked with three screens but I am afraid that we are locked into this awful design. Been pushed on me.

Comment: You have my sympathies - good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not tried it in an AD style environment but [mouse without borders](http://blogs.technet.com/b/next/archive/2011/09/09/microsoft-garage-download-mouse-without-borders.aspx) would let you do this with much less headache. Its supposed to support logging into multiple systems at once (and lets you clone input anyway, even at the startup screen - which would make an interactive install a lot easier). Hitting ctrl 3 times, and logging into one computer should log into the other two. Setup's pretty easy as well - you'd set one system as a master, and input a key into the other two. (There might be an easier way. I just don't set passwords on most of my home/home-lab systems where I run this ;p)

You'd have to run windows on all three, but.. well, The moment we did this on a heterogeneous network, things get messy fast.

The AD idea seems a little.. complicated since you'd still have to let the system know that another system has booted somehow.

Its still a dumb idea, but this might be a better hammer for driving in that pesky bolt. That said, Ebaying the spare boxen and getting proper triple head video cards sounds like a cheaper, more sensible solution on the short run

Comment: This looks like it might work actually. If it does that is brilliant, there are some bits to do in group policy first though. I'm going to test. I'll come back and let you know how I get on (after my impending week long holiday!). Thanks.

Comment: Its rough as hell and I can't see how it will get any better but this does actually work. I can successfully login to three computers at once with this tool. Heaven forbid that they aren't all focused exactly in the same place though. Thanks!